# access denied for user to create database

Tags: mysql

Im in hostgator cpanel , I have a script that creates databases for a multi-tenant app with laravel ..

when I tried the code on the server it shown an error of access denied .

the code is

```
DB::select("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_database");
```

but it throws the error

```
Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: create database test_database)
```

what can I do ?

Comment: Are you sure that db_user is having permission to create databases? Sometimes different users may have different permissions

Comment: The login data are invalid, the SQL query is unrelated to that error. Please verify your login data. It is unlikely that you username is `db_user`. Check with mysqli or PDO if you can login to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Hostgator doesn't allow their customers to run `CREATE DATABASE`. But their cpanel has a web user interface to create a database for the user.